# What is the difference between logb() and ilogb()?

Tags: c++, c

If I understand correctly, `ilogb()` will handle `0` and `NaN` arguments as well (and return `FP_ILOGB0` and `FP_ILOGBNAN`), while `logb()` throws a domain error. From what I see, there is no reason to use `logb()`. Are there any other differences between the 2 functions and is there any reason to use `logb()` instead of `ilogb()`?

Comment: You mean beyond the difference that one returns integers directly, and the other does not? Have you tried reading references such as [this `logb` one](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/logb) and [this `ilogb` one](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/ilogb)? What do they say more? Also, they could be implemented differently, providing certain optimizations not possible for the other use-case?

Comment: @Someprogrammerduden So is that the only difference? `ilogb()` returns integers and `logb()` returns floating-point values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the return types, and return values if the argument to the functions is zero, infinite or NaN, there is [no difference in the return value](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/ilogb#Notes) between the functions.

For `ilogb`:

> If arg is not zero, infinite, or NaN, the value returned is exactly equivalent to `static_cast<int>(std::logb(arg))`

However, there is a slight difference in the use of the functions w.r.t the POSIX standard.

For **[`ilogb`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/ilogb#Notes)**:

> POSIX requires that a domain error occurs if `arg` is zero, infinite, NaN, or if the correct result is outside of the range of `int`.
>
> POSIX also requires that, on XSI-conformant systems, the value returned when the correct result is greater than `INT_MAX` is `INT_MAX` and the value returned when the correct result is less than `INT_MIN` is `INT_MIN`.

For [**`logb`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/logb#Notes):

> POSIX requires that a pole error occurs if arg is `±0`.

Answer (score 0):

From [the POSIX standard for `ilogb`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ilogb.html):

> Upon successful completion, these functions shall return the exponent part of x as a signed integer value. They are equivalent to calling the corresponding [logb()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/logb.html) function and casting the returned value to type `int`.